# Bytecode manipulation - converting Bytecode representation to Java code representation

Tags: java, regex, java-bytecode-asm

For my bytecode analysis project, I am using ASM library to manipulate bytecodes. At bytecode level this method declaration in source code:

```
void m(int i, String s)
```

is represented as a String:

```
(ILjava/lang/String;)[I
     |__ Parameters   |__ Return type
```

here I am using string manipulation techniques to extract parameters out of that String. I need to get output like this in another String array: (So that I can convert byte code representation to corresponding Java representation):

```
{I,Ljava/lang/String;}
```

for this I have tried following regex to extract all the matches which Start with `L` and end with `;` (to get Strings which are in the form of Ljava/lang/String;, others I can manage):

```
/\L([^L;]+)\;/
```

But it is not returning me any matches. My question is:

- Can anyone help me to correct the above regex?
- Or better if anyone has worked on these type of manipulations can you point me if any API is available to convert `Bytecode representations --> Java code representations`?

Comment: What happens if you remove both backslashes from your regexp?  Oh, and Java regexps don't usually use forward slashes either; at least not the way Javascript does.

Comment: It's not matching again.@DavidWallace

Comment: Really?  Apart from an extra "L" (which you don't have any of anyway), it's exactly what Johannes's solution tells you to do.  Why did it work when he told you to do it, but not when I told you to do it?

Comment: @DavidWallace: Depending on how he's doing the actual search, the extra L might make a difference: If he's matching case insensitive (there is no reason to do so, but it's possible), the l in lang does end the capture in the first capturing group. As there is no ; afterwards, the whole match fails. For class names that contain a "L", this is even true for case sensitive matching.

Comment: @JohannesH. it will be always `L` and not `l`

Comment: I know, but that's not what I was talking about ;) My comment was on your regexp (mine doesn't have this problem): you're only matching characters that are not ; or L. Now if the class name itself is not String but something that contains an L, it won't match. As you told us that your regexp doesn't wokr even without the (wrong) backslashes, the only explanation is that you're either matching case-insensitive (so the `l` in lang does get in the way) or your String to test with isn't `String` but another class that has an `L` in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read `method desc` using `org.objectweb.asm.Type`

```
    String desc = "(ILjava/lang/String;)[I";

    // params
    for(Type type : Type.getArgumentTypes(desc)){
        System.out.println(type.getClassName());
    }

    //return type
    System.out.println(Type.getReturnType(desc).getClassName());
```

output

```
int
java.lang.String
int[]
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the regexp, this should do the trick (the parameter type is in the first capture group afterwards, the whole match does match the L and the ;, too)
`/L([^;]+);/`

And here is one that should match the return type (if the string ends after the return type... if you have omitted something, tell me):
`/\)\[(.+)$/`

Comment: This both looks good, it's working fine. Let me wait for answers for other part of question, if not I will accept this answer :)

Comment: Note that the frist regexp only matches ONE argument type. If there are multiple arguments, you have to change it to something like that (every argument gets its own capturing group now): `/L([^;]+)+/`